# replacing list items with editable forms

Tags: jquery, html

i have a couple questions about an idea i have to manage a form and input...

i'm printing out a long list of items, and when the user clicks on an item in the list, i want to use jquery to swap it out with an editable input box, where the user can then change the name of an item in the list. i've run into a couple issues though.

in my HTML, i have a `<form>` tag with `<li>`s in it, but no input boxes. I was using this code to swap the item with an input box...

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).html('<input type="text"> </input>');
});
```

This is swapping the text with a box, but anytime you click in the box to type, it resets it and sets it as an empty box again. i'm not sure how to solve that problem. is there some way to check that it's only been clicked once?

Another issue is I would like the text of the item to appear in the text box as placeholder text. Is there a way using query I can get the content of `(this)` and then print it out inside of the textbox on click?

Comment: I would probably render the form with the textboxes hidden inside the `<li>` and `show` it when you click the `<li>`, as well as a label to display the value of the textbox when the same is hidden.

Comment: So i tried hiding the inputs initially, and then showing them on a click, but when I click the item, it shows every text box on the page. How can I get it to only show the one i clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).html()+'" placeholder="'+$(this).html()+'" />');
});
```

You need to bind after an event on this input so you can play with your placeholder and others wanted functions.

EDIT: And when you submit the change, put every data-edit equal to 0 and put back using html()

```
$('li').click(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('data-edit') == '0'){
        jQuery(this).attr('data-edit', '1');
        $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).html()+'" placeholder="'+$(this).html()+'" />');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's swapping out the box with the proper text inside, but when I click again to edit the text, it prints out another text box and weird HTML including the placeholder variable word and some of the HTML tags and quotes...

Comment: Would there be a way to only run this on the FIRST click?

Comment: @patricko You could make it state based - either by checking for the presence of an `<input>` inside the `<li>`, checking for a specific class on the `<li>` or using a custom `data-*` HTML5 attribute. The class solution is probably easiest. Or, if you did only want it to ever recognise one click, you could use the `.one()` jQuery function to bind the event handler.

Comment: So could I start all the `<li>` with a certain class, and then change it to something different on the first click? And then I would check the first `<li>` to see if it has a 'clickable' class...

Comment: Do I manually assign the data-edit attr, or is that something built in to Jquery?

Comment: It is manually. Assign it by default like that `<li data-edit="0">`. `data-*` is HTML5 standard to create new property on element.

Comment: It will work everywhere. At least IE6+, but you are not coding for 0.0000000000001% of the world, remember that...

Answer (score 0):

use "statuses". When you create the elements, add special attributes to them so you will know if you are editing it or what. Use clases to better control.